# how do i update my P1_score and my P2_score so that it adds one point to either value?

Tags: python

i am making a pong game based off of clearcode's 2020 video about it and while i have been able to adapt the code to work w/ 3.9 python,  i haven't figured out how to update the text to add +1 to either the player's side or the computer's side.

code made:

```
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


Width = 1600
Length = 900
Line_Width = 15
Line_Color = (255, 255, 255)







Color = (0, 0, 0)
NetColor = (150, 150, 150)


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Length))
pygame.display.set_caption('Spy-pong!')
screen.fill(Color)


ball = pygame.Rect(Width/2 - 15, Length/2 - 15, 30, 30)

play_paddle = pygame.Rect(Width - 20, Length/2 - 70, 10, 140)

com_paddle = pygame.Rect(10, Length/2 - 70, 10, 140)


def ball_animation():   
    global ball_mspeed_x, ball_mspeed_y, P1_score, P2_score
    ball.x += ball_mspeed_x
    
    ball.y += ball_mspeed_y
    
    if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= Length:
        ball_mspeed_y *= -1
        
    if ball.left <= 0:
        P1_score += 1
        ball_restart()
        
    if ball.right >= Width:     
        P2_score += 1
        ball_restart()             
    
    if ball.colliderect(play_paddle) or ball.colliderect(com_paddle):
        ball_mspeed_x *= -1
        
ball_mspeed_x = 15 * random.choice((1, -1))
ball_mspeed_y = 15 * random.choice((1, -1))
player_speed = 0
com_speed = 13        

P1_score = 0
P2_score = 0
game_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",32)

def play_paddle_animation():
    play_paddle.y += player_speed
    if play_paddle.top <= 0:
        play_paddle.top = 0
    if play_paddle.bottom >= Length:
        play_paddle.bottom = Length

def com_paddle_ai():
   
    if com_paddle.top < ball.y:
        com_paddle.top += com_speed
    if com_paddle.bottom > ball.y:
        com_paddle.bottom -= com_speed
    if com_paddle.top <= 0:
        com_paddle.top = 0
    if com_paddle.bottom >= Length:
        com_paddle.bottom = Length  

def ball_restart():
    global ball_mspeed_x, ball_mspeed_y
    ball.center = (Width/2, Length/2)
    ball_mspeed_x *= random.choice((1,-1))
    ball_mspeed_y *= random.choice((1,-1))
 
def draw_rect():
        
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Line_Color, play_paddle)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Line_Color, com_paddle)
        
def draw_ellipse():
            
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, Line_Color, ball)
            
def draw_aaline():
    
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen, NetColor, (Width/2, 0), (Width/2, Length))

                

P1_text = game_font.render(f"{P1_score}",False,Line_Color)
screen.blit(P1_text,(835, 450))

P2_text = game_font.render(f"{P2_score}",False,Line_Color)
screen.blit(P2_text,(750, 450))    
     
    
while True:
    
    screen.fill(Color)
    
    screen.blit(P1_text, (835, 450))
    
    screen.blit(P2_text, (750, 450))
    
    draw_rect()

    draw_ellipse()

    draw_aaline()
    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.QUIT()
             sys.exit()
             
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    
             if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: 
                 player_speed += 15
             if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                 player_speed -= 15
         if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:    
             if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: 
                 player_speed -= 15
             if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                 player_speed += 15  
    
    
    
    ball_animation()
    play_paddle_animation()
    com_paddle_ai()           
    
   
                  
                
                
                
                
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

i tried repeating the screen.blit, but that did work and i was going to make a seperate screen.blit for the player += 1 variable, but that didn't pan out well as well. i  just need the text to update, as i have been getting the handle of modifying the 1.9.6 code used by clearcode to be used by 3.9 python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update the score text, you will need to render the updated scores each time the ball_animation() function is called.

Here's how you can update the score text:

Create new P1_text and P2_text surfaces inside the ball_animation() function that include the updated scores.

Replace the existing P1_text and P2_text surfaces in the main game loop with the new surfaces that include the updated scores.

Here's the updated ball_animation() function:
def ball_animation():
global ball_mspeed_x, ball_mspeed_y, P1_score, P2_score

```
# Update the ball position
ball.x += ball_mspeed_x
ball.y += ball_mspeed_y

# Check for collisions with walls and paddles
if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= Length:
    ball_mspeed_y *= -1
    
if ball.left <= 0:
    P1_score += 1
    P1_text = game_font.render(f"{P1_score}",False,Line_Color)
    ball_restart()
    
if ball.right >= Width:
    P2_score += 1
    P2_text = game_font.render(f"{P2_score}",False,Line_Color)
    ball_restart()

if ball.colliderect(play_paddle) or ball.colliderect(com_paddle):
    ball_mspeed_x *= -1
    
# Update the score text
P1_text = game_font.render(f"{P1_score}", False, Line_Color)
P2_text = game_font.render(f"{P2_score}", False, Line_Color)
```

And here's how you can update the score text in the main game loop:
while True:

```
# ...

# Update the screen with the new score text
screen.blit(P1_text, (835, 450))
screen.blit(P2_text, (750, 450))

# ...
```

Comment: i just implemented the code and  it now works!

Answer (score 0):

what I see is that in fact `P1_text` and `P2_text` are only rendered once, and this is before you main game loop is running, its possible that just re-rendering them before you call `blit` again will do the trick, like that:

```
# these lines can be commented out singe you are anyway printing the text 
#   at every cycle of the loop
#P1_text = game_font.render(f"{P1_score}",False,Line_Color)
#screen.blit(P1_text,(835, 450))

#P2_text = game_font.render(f"{P2_score}",False,Line_Color)
#screen.blit(P2_text,(750, 450))    
 

while True:
    screen.fill(Color)

    P1_text = game_font.render(f"{P1_score}",False,Line_Color)
    screen.blit(P1_text, (835, 450))
    P2_text = game_font.render(f"{P2_score}",False,Line_Color)
    screen.blit(P2_text, (750, 450))

    draw_rect()
```

Comment: i tried doing what  you tried @GalWeiss, but it didn't update the text itself